# How to fetch metafields for object "item" on Shopify search page

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I'm retrieving metafields in Product and Collection page as normal.

But the liquid used in Search page or normal pages is *item*, which shows something like this:

```
{{ item.title | link_to: item.url }}
```

so if I retrieve metafields like {{ products.metafields.global.key }} it wouldn't show up.

Is there anyway to retrieve metafields? I did try {{ item.metafields.global.key }}, doesn't work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get up to 20 products via collection.all_products[some_handle], so if item gives you a handle, ie) item.handle exists, then you can use that to get the actual products for at least 20 items on display.

Comment: Hi, I'm not looking for a way to display product grid on Search page. I'm looking for a way to retrieve metafields as said in the upper question.

Comment: Hold on, I'm not saying you're not helping c'mon man. Just want to clarify things out, since the Search page has already called 'item' to showcase the products. So by using your way I might need to delete all the 'item' and replace it with product handles instead. Just trying to figure out a way to connect these logics.

Comment: My logic, poor as it may be, was to simply use the info you might be given, ie) item handle, to use that to go get the product. Thing is, if item just represents a variant, you'd have to go up one level to item.product where you might just have a metafield. Or not. Either way, getting the product itself, gets you a Metafield too. Hence my advice. 

Since this is all Liquid, as junky as the algorithm sounds, you care not, since it all takes place on Shopify iron, and Liquid is way faster than monkeying around with callbacks or JS.